# Prorate multi year policy on date range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Prorate my multi year policies(on date range) in sql ex-

```
   plcy_nbr start date  end date    amount1 amount2

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93
```

output:

```
plcy_nbr    start date  end date    amount1 amount2 start_date_new  end_date_new    no_of_days  term    amount1_prorate amount2_prorate

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   12/19/2015  12/31/2015  13  366 20966.93108 5327.866366

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   1/1/2016    1/31/2016   31  366 49998.06643 12704.9121

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   2/1/2016    2/29/2016   29  366 46772.38473 11885.24036

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   3/1/2016    3/31/2016   31  366 49998.06643 12704.9121

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   4/1/2016    4/30/2016   30  366 48385.22558 12295.07623

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   5/1/2016    5/31/2016   31  366 49998.06643 12704.9121

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   6/1/2016    6/30/2016   30  366 48385.22558 12295.07623

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   7/1/2016    7/31/2016   31  366 49998.06643 12704.9121

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   8/1/2016    8/31/2016   31  366 49998.06643 12704.9121

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   9/1/2016    9/30/2016   30  366 48385.22558 12295.07623

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   10/1/2016   10/31/2016  31  366 49998.06643 12704.9121

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   11/1/2016   11/30/2016  30  366 48385.22558 12295.07623

a123    12/19/2015  12/18/2016  590299.7521 149999.93   12/1/2016   12/18/2016  18  366 29031.13535 7377.045738
```

Comment: your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @megha you need to provide more detail around logic for `start_date_new`, `end_date_new`, `amount1_new` and `amount2_new`

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do here with the logic and any calculation / formula. As it is, it doesn't say much

Comment: i have edited my expected output and my calculation for                    amount1_prorate=(amount1/term)*no_of_days....term calculate is start_date-end_date+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a recursive CTE to generate a number table. If you have one, use it.

```
; with
-- recursive cte to generate a number table for 0 to 1000
-- default no of recursion is 100 max.
-- to overwrite, use `option (maxrecursion 0)`
num as
(
    select  n = 0
    union all
    select  n = n + 1
    from    num
    where   n < 999
),
-- cte to calculate start_date_new & end_date_new
cte as
(
    select  
        t.*,
        days    = datediff(day, start_date, end_date) + 1,
        n.n,
        start_date_new  = case  
                          when  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.start_date) + n, 0) < t.start_date
                          then  t.start_date
                          else  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.start_date) + n, 0)
                          end,
        end_date_new    = case  
                          when  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.start_date) + n + 1, -1) < t.end_date
                          then  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.start_date) + n + 1, -1)
                          else  t.end_date
                          end
    from    your_tbl t
            inner join num n    on  n.n >= 0
                                and n.n <= datediff(month, t.start_date, t.end_date)
)
select  *,
        no_of_days = datediff(day, start_date_new, end_date_new) + 1,
        amount1_prorate = amount1 / days * (datediff(day, start_date_new, end_date_new) + 1),
        amount2_prorate = amount2 / days * (datediff(day, start_date_new, end_date_new) + 1)
from    cte
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response, it solves my 80% of my problem. one additional thing i am looking for is dynamically create 366, so here you have hard coded the value but lets say i have 3 year policy and there is 1 leap year in that 3 year policy,so i would like to calculate per day amount dynamically

Comment: i have already changed to calculate the terms from start and end date. Updated the query.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is really helful. i ran 1 policy data with code, it gives me right result but when i have multiple policies with there respective start date and end date, it throws an error "maximum recurrsion". can u assist me

Comment: add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the end of the query. Updated my query also

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what i am looking for:)

Comment: this is an old thread. Please start a new question

Answer (score 0):

This is one time  calendar table creation.

```
create table tblCalender1(DATEVal datetime not null)
insert into tblCalender1 (DATEVal)
select  dateadd(month, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by number)-1,'1900-01-01') from master..spt_values

create  clustered index ix_tblCal_Date on tblCalender1(DATEVal)
```

Last 2 column of your output is not clear.You make it clear then I will incorporate that in my script.

```
create table #tmp(plcy_nbr varchar(20), startdate date , enddate date ,   amount1 float, amount2 float)

insert into #tmp values ('a123','12/19/2015','12/18/2016', 590299.7521, 149999.93)

    ;

    WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT plcy_nbr
            ,startdate
            ,enddate
            ,amount1
            ,amount2
            ,CASE 
                WHEN startdate >= DATEVal
                    THEN startdate
                ELSE DATEVal
                END Newstartdate
            ,CASE 
                WHEN enddate <= dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DATEVal) + 1, 0))
                    THEN enddate
                ELSE dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DATEVal) + 1, 0))
                END Newenddate
        FROM #tmp t
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT tc.DATEVal
            FROM tblCalender tc
            WHERE tc.DATEVal >= dateadd(month, - 1, t.startdate)
                AND tc.DATEVal <= t.enddate
            ) ca
        )
    SELECT *
        ,DATEDIFF(day, Newstartdate, Newenddate) + 1 [No Of Days]

,DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate)+1 [Terms]

,(amount1/cast((DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate)+1) as decimal(5,2)))*(DATEDIFF(day, Newstartdate, Newenddate) + 1) as [amount1_prorate]

,(amount2/cast((DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate)+1) as decimal(5,2)))*(DATEDIFF(day, Newstartdate, Newenddate) + 1) as [amount2_prorate]
    FROM cte

    DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Calculstion for 2 column is: a)amount1_prorate=(amount1/term)*no_of_days b)amount2_prorate=(amount2/term)*no_of_days

Comment: @megha, got it meanwhile you check that your new requirement meet in my script or not.

Comment: checked the code but its working but but there is one additional row with 0 no. of days

Comment: @megha, no I am not getting any extra rows. My output is exactly same.May be you should share sample data where it not working ok.